# Memory leak after upgrading client to polkadot-0.9.22

Tags: nodes, memory

We just upgraded our node client to polkadot-0.9.22 and experienced regular memory leaks to all nodes. I tried to look into Prometheus but there is not much helpful information we can find out.

Have anyone got this experience before? or any hints that may cause the issue?

[image]

Comment: Polkadot is currently on release 0.9.26. Have you checked that later releases do still have this issue? Otherwise, it may already be resolved.

Comment: Hi @ShawnTabrizi, 

No we haven't started the upgrading to 0.9.26 yet. 

I am just wondering if there is any known issue with the 0.9.22 or common issues that other parachain team experienced so we can isolate if it's from our node implementation or from the release itself. 

As you mention, I think it's a good time for us to upgrade to 0.9.26 for our node client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was at least one known issue here that has been resolved in the latest releases:

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/11604
- https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/pull/1382

The best solution here is to upgrade to the latest client release.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @Shawn. I believe it caused the issue. Already updated our blockchain client to the latest, and it solved the problem.